# Best way to approach creating a sitemap with unique URLS (No Permalink Changes)

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I currently have been struggling mightily with a conundrum, I currently have a theme that is using day and name permalink settings so changing those settings are not possible, I'm attempting to make a sitemap for my theme that has a unique url structure.

Currently I have a sitemap wordpress page linked as `www.test.com/sitemap`, but I'm trying to add corresponding pages or posts to it that share the `sitemap` url parameter. I'm currently trying to do it with rewrite rules but I'm hitting dead ends constantly, as each link such as `today` or `2023` or `2023/01` need to be individual web pages.

Trying to make URLs such as

- `www.test.com/sitemap/today`
- `www.test.com/sitemap/yesterday`
- `www.test.com/sitemap/this-week`
- `www.test.com/sitemap/2023`
- `www.test.com/sitemap/2019`

However, the trickiest portion is creating a page or post that has this URL structure with a corresponding year to a corresponding month.

EX:

`www.test.com/sitemap/2023/01`

`www.test.com/sitemap/2023/02`

Essentially for all the years and months of articles published. Reaching out to people here to see if they know of the BEST way to get this to work, thank you all.